# Is this equation of in and output of a material right?

Tags: thermodynamics

> $\rm Q_{absorb} =ΔU+Q_{thermal \ radiation} +Q_{heat \ conduction}$

(Suggesting no heat expansion)

Should I consider Fourier's law of conduction and the Stefan-Boltzmann law to specify it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change in internal energy comes from

1. Heat power being transferred into it (times time)
2. Plus total work energy done on it, such as compression/expansion.
3. Maybe chemical/nuclear depending
4. Not phase transition as this is internal.

Heat goes in via

1. Net radiation (yes by Stefan-Boltzman),
2. Convection, which I don’t think you have included. This requires estimating a coefficient of convection. (If you are **not** assuming that youve reached steady state where the whole object is at around the same temperature, then you’ll need to determine internal thermal gradients, or use some estimating based on thermal diffusivity, because instantaneous convection depends on the object’s surface temperature not average temperature.)
3. Plus contact conduction, in which case you need to estimate the thermal contact resistance and estimate the thermal gradients from the surface being contacted (or use some estimating based on thermal diffusivity). Technically needs to be done even **if** steady state - because the object could have temperature gradients that continue. If the contacting object(s) is transferring heat symmetrically/uniformly then this last step won’t be needed after all.

Steady state:

$$\Delta U= 0=~ \dot{q}_{conduct}~ t+  \dot{q}_{convect} ~t+  \dot{q}_{radiate} ~t + work$$

For varying
$$dU= \dot{q}_{conduct} ~dt+  \dot{q}_{convect} ~dt+  \dot{q}_{radiate}~ dt + dw$$

Which you could integrate for $\Delta U$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering of what's going on the central tower of Concentrated Solar Power. Supposing the material being hit by sun ray is soild, I thought the highest temperature will be when the losing heat and earning heat(per time) is equal, and that's why I did not consider convection. Besides thermal gradients are difficult for students like me:( It was very helpful!

Comment: You might search this site for questions about “solar furnaces”. There is one hard theoretical limit that they could never achieve hotter than the sun because any light going to it would be equally going back to the sun as the object radiates more as it heats.

Comment: Are you saying that, when liquid converts to vapor within a system there is no change in internal energy?

Comment: No Im saying that is not a separate term because it doesnt generate its own energy to do so. It still takes the heat or work input and still increases internal energy that amount whether it goes to temp increase or phase transition. Because i thought maybe one of the terms in the q was about phase transition